# How to use CQL in cassandra?

Tags: c#, windows, cassandra, cql

I have run cassandra server (or how it will be called) on Windows 7 by using  [this article](http://php-cms-job.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-install-cassandra-and-configure.html)

It tells me that to start to will database (create keyspace and ...) I should run `cassandra-cli.bat` file. As I understand, this is not CQL. I also have `cqlsh.bat` file but it close itself immediately.

How can I use CQL after setting up Cassandra?

P.S Sorry for stupid question, but I really cant find any normal direct answer.

Comment: what is the error log?

Comment: error log? Why shoul I have it?

Comment: because there was an error starting cql..

Comment: I don't understand you at all. Error... where should it appear? In cqlsh.bat?

Comment: yes.. open the .bat file in edit mode.. and at the end write `pause`.. and run it again to see logs.. or you can just see in cassandra's log folder..

Comment: It says "Can't detect Python version!"

Comment: You should consider installing Cassandra on a Linux machine instead.  Aside from Windows not being supported (except for development...*if* you can *make* it work) `cqlsh` and Python should run without any special installation procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run CQL.. you need to have python installed in your machine. You can follow this [tutorial](http://devasive.blogspot.in/2012/10/cql-terminal-for-cassandra-on-windows.html) for setting up CQL terminal in windows.

HTH

Comment: Is there a some special way to inslall it?

Comment: after installing you should be able to run cqlsh.bat..

Comment: And... still not working. No reaction on python setup.py install at all. I'm ready to smash my monitor with keyboard already =(

Comment: no command supplied, this is what those files are telling me

Comment: was doing it wrong. After correcting path, managed to run those libs.